# How to properly criticize/comment on literature without being offensive?

Tags: publications, peer-review

For example, many of the published papers didn't take A into account when running some simulations to calculate B and I am trying to address the importance of A in my paper. How should I properly comment and/or criticize the existing work?

Suppose I say something like this: most of the existing works omit A when calculating B, which can lead to the wrong conclusion. I feel it is too aggressive and offensive. Alternatively, if I say it very mildly, the importance of my work may be not clear to the audience. So, my question is, what is the proper way to stress the importance without being offensive? Also, should I cite some of the papers that didn't take A into account?

Comment: I don't believe the first version is aggressive.   Stick to the facts.  Don't sugar-coat just to please authors.  If a work is wrong or has limitation, just say so.  It's OK to say equation A does not consider X; don't write 'the authors did not think of X'.

Comment: It is not offensive or aggressive at all. Pointing out other papers' limitations and weaknesses with an objective tune and highlighting your research strength is the common way to organize the introduction part/literature review (thesis).

Comment: Just to answer all the concerns about me strongly believing in the hypothesis, it is because it has been tested against many other techniques we used except for the one. Also, I am not saying the hypothesis is flawless. It certainly can be improved.

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing offensive about noting a limitation in an existing method, and what you want to write does not strike me as offensive to begin with.  If existing works didn't take A into account then they didn't take A into account, and it is okay to say this clearly and openly.  Nevertheless, if you want to temper your critique to be as charitable as possible to existing works (which is generally a reasonable idea), you can do this by also stressing the merits of the methods you are criticising before pointing out their limitations.

I once wrote a paper where I developed an algorithm that gives exact results for a problem where existing methods gave only approximations (sometimes incorrect).  In that particular case, my own algorithm was more narrowly tailored to a smaller class of problems than the existing methods, but it worked better in that narrow class of problems.  In my exposition of this algorithm I made it a point to stress that the drawback of the other methods (e.g., giving only an approximate solution) were a result of their greater generality, and that these were still useful methods in broader problems.  In that case it was unclear whether the existing methods were intended to solve the problem I was dealing with, so I merely noted that they didn't clearly rule it out-of-bounds, but only gave an approximate solution that was sometimes in error.  That is the kind of thing we do to ensure that the reader understands the value of existing work, but also its limitations.

Remember that academic research work typically involves innovation over existing methods/knowledge, so ideally new work will bring some improvement to existing work.  This means that there is usually some limitation in existing work presenting a "gap" that is being filled by the new work.  In order to explain the contribution of your own paper, it is perfectly appropriate to clearly articulate the limitations of existing work and the resulting "gap" in knowledge that you are addressing.  Ideally, other researchers will build on your own work in turn and address limitations in your own work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say something that may be viewed as negative, simply state it without being too colorful with adjectives and you should be fine. Also, Most universities have writing centers or services that help with this type of thing if you prefer having someone review your writing before you submit it. I've used them multiple times in the past, there's no shame in it and it definitely helps you and gives you reassurance.